# How to use a function when updating a mongo document (is this possible)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to update my mongo document so that my image path is require([Image Path]) so it can be better integrated in a react app. I am trying the following with no luck.

```
db.movies.update(
... {_id: ObjectId("61eda33c2db24d3bf8793079")},
... {$set: {ImagePath: require("../images/avatar.jpg")}})
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: require is not defined :
@(shell):3:9
```

Comment: What environment is the code running in? Node or browser?

Comment: It is running in node